# CNN based regression with words input

Tags: deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network

I successfully trained a CNN with regression output layer to predict a numerical indicator of the image. Further, I would like to encode the description of each image into CNN to get better regression performance.

My data are a series of x-ray images in 512 x 512. Each image has a description recording how the image was taken. For example, the description of image #1 is

```
Voltage: 40V
Current: 2A
Shuttle speed: 1 sec
Filter material: rhodium
```

the description of image #2 is

```
Voltage: 38V
Current: 1.7A
Shuttle speed: 0.7 sec
Filter material: tungsten
```

the description of other images are very similar, just with different parameters.

My question is: how can I encode these description into CNN?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only dozens of possible values to the attributes, I would suggest learning embeddings for each of the attribute-value pairs and concatenate them with the CNN outputs and perhaps add one hidden layer on top of that so the textual and image features can more interact with each other.

If the texts are not so well structured, I would process the text with an RNN (i.e., tokenize the text, embed the tokens, feed them into an RNN and take the final state). This will give you a single vector for the text description that you can again concatenate to the CNN output.